# How to stop an audio file from looping in Apple's MixerHost Core Audio Example

Tags: iphone, c, core-audio

I've got an app that allows a user to record over a beat using audio units. To achieve this I've modified the Mixer class from Apple's MixerHost example code.

Currently my sound file loops and I want to stop that. I'd like the user to be able to save the mix once the sound file is through.

The reason for the loop is a `for loop` in the last line of the following section of the `inputrendercallback` function:

```
for (UInt32 frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inNumberFrames; ++frameNumber) {

        outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]                 = dataInLeft[sampleNumber];
        if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]  = dataInRight[sampleNumber];

        sampleNumber++;

        // After reaching the end of the sound stored in memory--that is, after
        //    (frameTotalForSound / inNumberFrames) invocations of this callback--loop back to the 
        //    start of the sound so playback resumes from there.
        if (sampleNumber >= frameTotalForSound) sampleNumber = 0;
    }
```

I realize that I need to change `if (sampleNumber >= frameTotalForSound) sampleNumber = 0;` in order to tell the callback to stop requesting samples once the samples have been exhausted, but I'd be far more comfortable calling methods in objective C than I am manipulation this C-Struct.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only imagine that many people must have encountered this audio file loop issue because MixerHost is one of the precious few Core Audio examples that Apple provides.

I solved this issue by using the NSNotificationCenter. Before decrying the use of Objective C inside of a C function, please recognize that I found this solution by mimicking other parts of Apple's code in the MixerHost example itself. For instance, to pause the program and indicate that headphones were unplugged, or that the device was removed from a dock connector, Apple used the notification center in the MixerHostAudio class's `audioRouteChangeListenerCallback`:

```
 if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {

            NSLog (@"Audio output device was removed; stopping audio playback.");
            NSString *MixerObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification = @"MixerObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification";
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: MixerObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object: audioObject];
```

I decided to also post a notification from within the `inputrendercallback` function:

```
for (UInt32 frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inNumberFrames; ++frameNumber) {

        if (sampleNumber == frameTotalForSound) {

            NSString *AudioFileFinishedPlaying = @"AudioFileFinishedPlaying";
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: AudioFileFinishedPlaying object: nil];
        }

        outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]                 = dataInLeft[sampleNumber];
        if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]  = dataInRight[sampleNumber];

        sampleNumber++;

...
```

I then used the  `addObserver:selector:name:object:` method in another part of the program to get the loop to stop and to perform other tasks germane to my app.

I hope that this is helpful. If anyone has a better solution, then I'm open to receive it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use any Objective C messaging in the inner loops of audio processing or buffer callbacks.  Too much cycle overhead for no reason.  Stick to using the intrinsic C types in the C struct.  Setting a flag variable is OK.  Do any needed object messaging later outside the callback and the inner audio sample loops.

Comment: can you explain what you mean @hotpaw2? i solved this issue by registering with the NSNotificationCenter from within the callback and stopping the audiograph with a method in another part of the program, but if you can outline a cleaner, C solution then i'd be grateful.

Comment: A solution that works does not necessarily look cleaner.  Setting a flag and polling it is a common working solution, even if "ugly".

Comment: That's not what I meant hotpaw. I was saying that if you could help me with a solution that was better or "cleaner" than mine, that I would definitely welcome it. As far as I understood, my solution was the "dirty" one, but I'm beginning to think that it may be OK. So, if I'm wrong please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your solution, it works and is not inconsistent with the way Apple has declared the other notifications. A few notes:

1. If you are mixing multiple files, this will stop the player when the shortest file reaches its end.
2. I tried the following code (assume the rest of the inputrendercallback function is unchanged) :

   if (sampleNumber >= frameTotalForSound) {
   NSLog(@"Reached the end!");
   THIS.stopAUGraph;
   sampleNumber = 0; // in case one wants to play again
   }